# How to position plus sign right in the middle of circle

Tags: swiftui

i trying to position plus sign in the middle of circle, but it doesnt work properly and goes a little bit lower

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {print("add")}, label: {
        Circle()
            .accentColor(.green)
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
            .overlay(Text("+").accentColor(.white), alignment: .center)
        }))
```

[image]

Comment: What’s the reason not to use SFSymbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Image(systemName: "plus").foregroundColor(.white)` instead of `Text("+")`

In text "+" symbol doesn't have to be in the middle of the view because of text layout.

`SFSymbol`s are more convenient in this regard. Also you can specify size with `.font(.system(size: 10))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this button. Here size is the same as yours, but the tappable area is larger.

```
struct YourReusableButton: View {
    
    var action: (() -> Void)? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
            Button(action: buttonAction) {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .imageScale(.small)
                        .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                }
            }.padding()
        }
        
    
    func buttonAction() { action?() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use offset to adjust the text position, like this:

```
Text("+").offset(x: -1, y: -2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Text's `baselineOffset` modifier to adjust the text vertical offset. But that's not a good idea.

You should use an image object such as SFSymbol image or PNG image.